# Parse SDK SignUp and Login through single API call

Tags: android, parse-platform

In Parse SDK we have two different APIs for signup and for login,

But in my case, i wanted to show a simple login form with username and password where the user can signup or signin, when the user clicks on signup/signin button, Parse backed should find out if the user already exists or not and returns the ParseUser object,

and in the client side, we will use ParseUser.isNew() method to determine if the user has signedup newly or signing in.

So is there a way to do this with just a single API call?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to perform a sign in call, and in your error handler check the error and try sign up instead.

For most users this will be a single API call, for those that are new it will be two API calls.

Comment: I am doing the same now.. but just trying to see if there is anything available for regular signup, as there is already a provision to see if the user is new or already signedup in facebook login